# Referencing static string in Xcode UI test with apostrophe

Tags: swift, string, escaping, xctest, xcuitest

In my project is a localized string in a *.strings file like this...

```
"some_key" = "Yada yada won't blah.\nBlah blah?";
```

In my UI Test, when I record the element and when I print object on the staticTexts dictionary, it's referenced with a string like this...

```
app.staticTexts["Yada yada won't blah.\nBlah blah?"]
```

However, in my test I localize the key and the string comes out with an extra escape character for the apostrophe in the contraction which I believe is breaking the label reference...

```
print("some_key".localized)
Yada yada won\'t blah.\nBlah blah?
```

I've tried replacing "\'" with "'" and even the below code...

```
let begin = id.substring(start: 0, offsetBy: 15)
let end = id.substring(start: 16, offsetBy: 41)
id = "\(begin ?? "")'\(end ?? "")"
```

...but the escape is always there.

**How do I keep the break line, but remove the escape on the apostrophe?**

I don't control the client code being tested, so I can't change how the text is setup and I can't reference with an accessibility identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [the replacingOccurrences(of:with:) function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412937-replacingoccurrences).

```
cleaned = id.replacingOccurences(of: "\'", with: "'")
```

Comment: I tried originally with replacingFirstOccurence, double checked with replacingoccurences... The escape is still there.

Comment: Peculiar. I’ve checked your input and output strings and they’re both simple backslashes. 

Are you doing the replacement on the localized string?

Comment: Capturing the localized string in a variable, then storing the results of replace methods in a separate variable. When I run po on the var with a breakpoint, it shows the escapes :( I've been able to get around it by capturing app.alerts.firstMatch and comparing it's description which has the escape in it.

Comment: Glad you've found a workaround, but still very odd. Possibly a bug?

Comment: Might be the way it was setup, although our 'localized' computed property just calls the built in string localization method. I actually got one of the client side devs to add the escape on the apostrophe from their end; but the static strings dictionary still stripped it out (while leaving the newline). I'm loath to say it's an issue with UIKit, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Is it reasonable to convert your string from using `'` to using `’`? Using `’` is typographically more correct :-) The `’` is made by typing `option shift ]`